# Determination of the quotient of an affine variety by a reductive group by computer

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a program (in Macaulay2 or singular or Gap or whatever) which explicitly gives the ring structure of $Spec[V]^G$ where $V$ is an explicitly given affine variety (over $\mathbb{C}$) and $G$ a reductive group acting on $V$ ?

As a background: in supersymmetric quantum field theory, we often come across so-called Seiberg dualities, one of whose consequences is that two quotients $Spec[V]^G$ and $Spec[W]^H$ are the same. Therefore it's important for us to check the equality, but doing this by hand is often extremely tedious. So I'm looking for a way to automate it.

Comment: Perhaps the Singular library called "rinvar_lib" (the documentation for which is in "Appendix D.7 Invariant Theory" in the manual) has the features that you need.

Comment: This seems way too hard. If G=SL2 and V=Sym^d(C^2) that's the ring of invariants for binary forms. I think it is only known up to d=10.

Comment: @James-Parson Thanks, I'll have a look. @Abdelmalek Yes, but I was asking if there's an algorithm implemented in a computer algebra system. If that algorithm finishes in a reasonable amount of time is a separate question...

Answer (score 2):

In principle if one has an a priori degree bound on the generators for the ring of invariants then one has a brute force algorithm. Such a bound was found by Popov.
See for instance:

H. Derksen, H. Kraft, [Constructive Invariant Theory](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hderksen/preprints/DK-ConstIT.pdf), Algèbre non commutative, groupes quantiques et invariants (Reims, 1995), 221-244, Sémin. Congr. 2, Soc. Math. France, Paris, 1997.

Another general algorithm is in:
H. Derksen, [Computation of reductive group invariants](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hderksen/preprints/invar.ps), Adv. in Math. 141 (1999), 366-384. 
There is also [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=sHQ5E_t76S8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Computational+Invariant+Theory&hl=en&src=bmrr&ei=E9xgTr-dIaLm0QHS160F&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

If you want an algorithm which runs in a reasonable time, then you probably need an algorithm which is custom-made for the problem at hand, rather than the most general algorithm.
For the case of binary forms I mentioned, I believe the most efficient algorithm is the one given by Gordan in 1868, but it has never been run on computer.

Answer (score 1):

The search term here is "Invariant Theory", plus something like "algorithm" or "computational". The two standard books are

[Algorithms in Invariant Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=3lF0cyOHwgQC), by Bernd Sturmfels

[Computational Invariant Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=sHQ5E_t76S8C), by Harm Derksen and Gregor Kemper.

I must admit that I haven't read either, although I can generally say that Bernd and Harm are both good writers.